# How to SUM multiple INDEX+MATCH results

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table of tournament placings for a group of players and a table of tournament payouts per placement, and I want to add all the winnings without having to create any extra tables or a massive formula.

This is what I imagined might work:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(Tournaments!$1:$1000,MATCH($H$1:$Q$1,Tournaments!$A:$A,0),MATCH($H4:$Q4,Tournaments!$1:$1,1))))
```

Basically expecting the arrayformula to turn the Index into a lot of distinct matches to be able to sum them, but instead it is only bringing the first hit. Small thing to note: Placings are not necessarily exact, if a player placed 3-4th, the table has a 3.5, which is why the Match formula above had a 1 (a -1 does the same thing) instead of a 0 on Search Type.

Here is the link to the file if you want to play around with it. Formula goes on column G:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ft_E5bRzlqbAvo3yD54VC2hBWS6eaYrLQg5Q9sP859g/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you elaborate on an example for a single player?

Comment: Yes. For example, TheViper played on 6 tournaments. I want the formula to add all the money he won on those six tournaments, i.e. 2nd place at Red Bull Wololo I = 3263 + 2nd place at Battle of Africa = 4000, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got it. (Thank for providing the Sheet!)

You can't use `INDEX()` and `ArrayFormula()`, sadly, but you *can* use `VLOOKUP()` to get it to work. I also decided to make `Tournaments` a named range for readability.

Flat form:

```
=SUM(ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(H$1:Q$1,Tournaments,IF(H4:Q4,H4:Q4+3),0))))
```

Marked up:

```
=SUM(
    ArrayFormula(
        IFERROR(                # If we don't find a value, we get an error, 
                                #   meaning a valid placement was not given. 
                                #   No 2nd arg -> blank -> `0` for `SUM()`.
            VLOOKUP(
                H$1:Q$1,        # Lookup value (Tournament names)
                Tournaments,    # Lookup range (Named range)
                IF(             # Lookup index (Placement)
                                # No need to worry about floating points.
                                #   This value is floored by VLOOKUP().
                    H4:Q4,      # If non-blank...
                    H4:Q4+3     # Add 3 to index into proper column
                ),
                0               # Exact match on tourney name, since 
                                #   they're unsorted
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Clarifications to help:

- `VLOOKUP()` looks *vertically* for the lookup value (tournament name) first, retrieving the row. *Then* it indexes this row using the index (placement). This is why we need the whole table and included all the columns.

  - This is why the +3 is there.
- Automatic flooring turns 3.5 into 3.
- Named ranges can be created under `Data` > `Named Ranges` in the menu.
- I made the formula draggable, so the rows will properly increment.

Comment: Yes! This makes sense. I actually thought about this and thought "why would VLOOKUP work and not INDEX", but now that I think about it, it makes sense. I haven't checked if it works, but the only issue is you actually don't want to only get exact matches, since the players that finished 3-4 have a 3.5 placing, and therefore we want it to match it to either the 3 or the 4 (so fourth argument should be a 1 or TRUE). Thanks!

Comment: @MarianoMolina Sorry. Wasn't clear. The fourth arg is for `is_sorted`, which we need because the tourney list is not sorted. The exact match is to look up the tourney name, not the placement, so the 0 is needed. Argument 3 is our indexer for the placement, which is automatically "floored" by the `VLOOOKUP` in the third arg. I'll update.

Comment: That makes sense. Yep, the tournament name should be matched exactly, I missinterpreted the formula. I checked and it works great. Thanks man, great job!

Comment: @MarianoMolina Understandable. I had exactly the same confusion when I was researching this.